# Highcharts Wind rose increase surface bar

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to increase width of each data in order to fill the blank data?
For example, I want to merge "1" and "2" bar I need to keep the shape of the grey cross in the center:

but i need to keep the shape of the grey cross in the center

```
data: [
  {
    y: 0,
    color: 'transparent'
  }, {
    y: 100,
    color: 'green',
    name: "1"
  }, {
    y: 0,
    color: 'transparent'
  }, {
    y: 100,
    color: 'green',
    name: "2"
  }
```

JSfiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/kv9oLadb/

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can create additional series to fill the space, for example:

```
series: [{
  ...
}, {
  grouping: false,
  showInLegend: false,
  pointRange: 5,
  data: [{
    color: 'green',
    y: 100
  }]
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/w5kuz6fv/1/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.pointRange

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.grouping

Comment: Thanks! How can I start in the middle of the quarter circle? In order to divide this quarter in half.

Comment: Hi @Shakespeare, Just set `x` value: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/w5kuz6fv/2/